# Websites won't load beside having Connection

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet, browser, internet-connection

Since today I'm not able to load webpages on my pc. This happened after I resumed the suspended Windows.

I am connected to my Router via WLan (tried lan, lan via wlan client; no difference) and while all other computers in this household have proper working Internet, this PC in particular refuses to load webpages. We also have a repeater installed here, but also tried turning it off.

I tried loading webpages in Chrome, Firefox and IE 11, all browsers won't load any site (Even the steam internal browser). Sometimes though I am able to load youtube and google.com, but beside those two pages none will load. And those only load occasionally.. I tried to ping 8.8.8.8 (google), my server and google.de. Each of them had a very normal latency. I also tried tracert on some pages, all resolved fine, no problems with DNS or any routing. Also, steam, teamviewer and skype will continue to work properly, altough thunderbird refuses to connect to the mail servers ~50% of the time.

So I thought "shitty adapter here - reinstall drivers". But nope. "netsh int ip reset" - nope. "ipconfig /release", "ipconfig /flushdns" and "ipconfig /renew" - also not working. So I tried to use a system restore point, which was created the day before while installing some Windows updates. Now the adapter won't even start, but in the meanwhile I've fixed that - still not working. I read somewhere about some conflicting DMA and IRQ stuff, so I plugged it into another PCI slot (which was how I fixed the error 10 on the adapter), but still not working.

Well, still could be the wlan adapter, so I grabbed my allnet mini router which acts as a client for the wlan and plugged it into the realtek card. Still not working, though. I even tried USB tethering, but also for no good. So it's not the adapters fault.

Next I got the stupid idea to boot into secure mode with network - and look: No problems there! Everything is working fine (beside looking ugly). So I've installed ccleaner (read somewhere it helped someone having the same problem), but, well, it wasn't my best idea. Didn't damage anything though. Next I've tried autoruns from sysinternals and removed everything not necessary for my workflow. When I restarted to normal mode, it was still not working. So I blamed my Virus Scanner (Kaspersky btw) and disabled it. Wasn't the problem though.

I also had Installed the microsoft loopback device. Uninstalled it now, but still not working. I don't have any VPN adapters installed.

Now I'm a bit helpless and want to avoid reinstalling Windows7 again just for this stupid "whatever-it-is". Any ideas on how to get a grip on the real error?

Edit: I also found out, that all network drives hosted on this pc stopped working with "the local device name is already in use"

Comment: Did you try restarting your router and/or your pc?

Comment: Did both several times, no change.